# Android SDK file not found: adb

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-sdk-2.3

I install the android studio to start learning flutter when I run in the command prompt "flutter doctor"
this message " Android SDK file not found: adb." appeared on my console I tried uninstalling the android studio and re-installing it didn't work ... any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow. You're missing the Android Debug Bridge which is in the Android SDK Platform-Tools. In Android Studio:

- click Tools > SDK Manager
- click on the `SDK Tools` tab
- check the checkbox next to "Android SDK Platform-Tools"
- click Apply or OK.

Then add the path to `adb` to your `$PATH`/`%PATH%` environment variable if it's not already there.